# In Postgres, how can I efficiently filter using the inner numbers of this jsonb structure?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

So I work with Postgres SQL, and I have a jsonb column with the following structure:

```
{
   "Store1":[
      {
         "price":5.99,
         "seller":"seller"
      },
      {
         "price":56.43,
         "seller":"seller"
      }
   ],
   "Store2":[
      {
         "price":45.65,
         "seller":"seller"
      },
      {
         "price":44.66,
         "seller":"seller"
      }
   ]
}
```

I have a jsonb like this for every product in the database. I want to run an SQL query that will answer the following question:
For each product, is one of the prices in this JSON is bigger/equal/smaller than X?

Basically filter the product to include only the ones who have **at least one price** that satisfies a mathematical condition.
How can I do it efficiently? What's the best way in Postgres to iterate a JSON like this, with a relatively complex inner structure?

Also, if I could control the way the data is structured (to an extent, I can), what changes can I do to make this query more efficient?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a [json path expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH):

```
WHERE col @@ '$.*[*].price < 20'
```

or

```
WHERE col @? '$.*[*] ? (@.price < 20)'
```

If you need to compare to another column or make the query parameterised, you can either build the jsonpath dynamically

```
WHERE col @@ format('$.*[*].price < %s', $1)::jsonpath
WHERE col @? format('$.*[*] ? (@.price < %s)', $1)::jsonpath
```

or you can use the respective function and pass variables as an object:

```
WHERE jsonb_path_match(col, '$.*[*].price < $limit', jsonb_build_object('limit', $1))
WHERE jsonb_path_exists(col, format('$.*[*] ? (@.price < $limit)', jsonb_build_object('limit', $1))
```

---

I admit I had to check [my cheat sheet](https://dbfiddle.uk/7O1QfG4b) to figure out the right combination of operator and expression. Takeaways:

- if a comparison operator needs to work with multiple values, it generally functions as an `ANY`
- `@@` does not work with `? (@ …)` filter expressions since they don't return a boolean,
  `@?` does not work with predicates since they always return a value (even if it's `false`)

Comment: I have to admit I am also sometimes confused about the usage of `@@` and `@?` until I realized that if my JSON path uses a `?` I have to use the operator with the `? `:)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah, that's a good mnemonic

Comment: @Bergi thanks, your method works great! But how do I use it to compare to values from another column, rather than a fixed number?

Instead of comparing to 20, I would like to compare to some other joined table.column, but I can't quite figure out the syntax or find it in the documentation you sent. Care to help? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't going to be efficient.  The index might be used to find all the rows which contain a 'price' (which will presumably be all the rows) but then all of those rows will need to get rechecked to see if any price meets the numerical criteria.

Comment: @jjanes True! Have a look at my second answer please, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

> What changes can I do to make this query more efficient?

As @jjanes commented on my other answer, the jsonpath match `col @@ '$.*[*].price < $limit'` isn't going to be fast and needs to do full table scan, at least for `<` and `>`. To make a useful index, a different approach is required. An index can only have a single value to compare with, not any number. For that, we need to change the condition from `EXISTS(SELECT prices_of(col) WHERE price < $limit)` to `(SELECT MIN(prices_of(col))) < $limit`.

With this idea it is possible to build an [expression index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.htmlhttps://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) on the result of a custom immutable function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION min_price(data jsonb) RETURNS float
  LANGUAGE SQL
  IMMUTABLE
  RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
  RETURN (
    SELECT min((offer ->> 'price')::float)
    FROM jsonb_each(data) AS entries(name, store),
    LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(store) AS elements(offer)
  );

CREATE INDEX example_min_data_price_idx ON example (min_price(data));
```

which you can use as

```
SELECT * FROM example WHERE min_price(data) < 20;
```

Looking for rows with a price larger than a certain number requires a separate index on `max_price(data)`. If you want to use the index in a `JOIN` with more conditions, consider making it a multi-column index.

Looking for row with a price equalling a certain number can be optimised by [indexing the jsonb column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING) and using a jsonpath:

```
CREATE INDEX example_data_idx ON example USING GIN (data jsonb_ops);
SELECT * FROM example WHERE data @@ '$.*[*].price == 20';
SELECT * FROM example WHERE data @? '$.*[*] ? (@.price == 20)';
```

Unfortunately you can't use `jsonb_path_ops` here since that doesn't support the wildcard.