# What's the difference between the PostgreSQL @? and @@ JSONB Operators?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, jsonpath

I've been trying to understand the difference between the PostgreSQL `@?` and `@@` [JSONB operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html). Why do these return different results?

```
david=#  SELECT '{ "email": { "main": "hi@example.net" } }' @? '$ ?(@.email.main == "hi@example.net")';
 ?column? 
----------
 t

david=#  SELECT '{ "email": { "main": "hi@example.net" } }' @@ '$ ?(@.email.main == "hi@example.net")';
 ?column? 
----------
 f
```

I thought maybe they're equivalent to the `jsonb_path_exists()` and `jsonb_path_match()` functions:

```
david=#  SELECT jsonb_path_exists('{ "email": { "main": "hi@example.net" } }', '$ ?(@.email.main == "hi@example.net")');
 jsonb_path_exists 
-------------------
 t

david=#  SELECT jsonb_path_match('{ "email": { "main": "hi@example.net" } }', '$ ?(@.email.main == "hi@example.net")');
ERROR:  single boolean result is expected
```

That's a bit more informative, and `jsonb_path_match()` example in [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) show the use of `exists()`, and that does seem to work:

```
david=#  SELECT jsonb_path_match('{ "email": { "main": "hi@example.net" } }', 'exists($ ?(@.email.main == "hi@example.net"))');
 jsonb_path_match 
------------------
 t
```

But the same is not true of `@@`:

```
david=#  SELECT '{ "email": { "main": "hi@example.net" } }' @@ 'exists($ ?(@.email.main == "hi@example.net"))';
 ?column? 
----------
 f
```

So color me confused. I do not understand the differences here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With thanks to @jjanes for pointing me in the right direction, and to the denizens of the pgsql-hackers mail list, I believe I got the differences worked out. [This blog post](https://justatheory.com/2023/10/sql-jsonpath-operators/) details figuring it out, but the conclusion is this:

- Postgres supports a nonstandard syntax for SQL/JSON path queries where the entire query can be a boolean predicate, and the value returned by the query is the value returned by the predicate: `true`, `false`, or `unknown` (translated to SQL `null`).
- `@?` (and `jsonb_path_exists()`) returns true if the path query returns any values --- even `false` or `null` --- and false if it returns no values. This operator should be used *only* with SQL-standard JSON path queries that select data from the JSONB. Do not use predicate-only JSON path expressions with `@?`.
- `@@` (and `jsonb_path_match()`) returns true if the path query returns the single boolean value `true` and false otherwise. This operator should be used *only* with Postgres-specific boolean predicate JSON path queries, that return data from the predicate expression. Do not use SQL-standard JSON path expressions with `@@`.

Comment: Great, this confirms [my previous experiments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75273850/1048572), which also found [what happens](https://dbfiddle.uk/7O1QfG4b) when you use a boolean predicate against multiple values (e.g. from an array)

Comment: Oh, very nice, @Bergi!

Answer (score 1):

Try visualizing with this:

```
SELECT jsonb_path_query('{ "email": { "main": "hi@example.net" } }', '$ ?(@.email.main == "hi@example.net")');
```

The above does return something, which why is why @? is true.  But what it returns is not the boolean value 'true', which is why @@ is false.  And is not a boolean at all, which is why jsonb_path_match gives an error.  That is my casual interpretation of it, anyway.

This is all very subtle, and I find the docs are hard to understand unless you already know what they are saying.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I can use `$.email.main == "hi@example.net"` (PostgreSQL-specific syntax) to select a bool, and that does indeed work. Also `exists($ ?(@.email.main == "hi@example.net"))`. Thanks for the pointer to `jsonb_path_query()`, making a mental note to test paths with that function to make sure they return booleans to use with `jsonb_path_match()`. The docs could use some explication on the need for a boolean and typical path expressions to produce one.