# The difference of @@ @? operators of jsonb in Postgres[14+]?

Tags: postgresql

With postgres documentation I can't find the difference between `@@` `@?` operator。
[According to the Postgres Documentation of JSONB functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE):

- `jsonb @? jsonpath → boolean`

> Does JSON path return any item for the specified JSON value?
> `'{"a":[1,2,3,4,5]}'::jsonb @? '$.a[*] ? (@ > 2)' → t`

- `jsonb @@ jsonpath → boolean`

> Returns the result of a JSON path predicate check for the specified JSON value. Only the first item of the result is taken into account. If the result is not Boolean, then NULL is returned.
> `'{"a":[1,2,3,4,5]}'::jsonb @@ '$.a[*] > 2' → t`

I test the the code below, I suppose `@@`opeartor should output the true value but it output null ,
Can you tell me why ?

```
select
  '{"city": "Ricy", "state": "0"}'::jsonb @@ '$.city == "Ricy" && $.state == "0" ',     -- output: true
  '{"city": "Ricy", "state": "0"}'::jsonb @? '$ ?(@.city == "Ricy" && @.state == "0")', -- output: true
  '{"city": "Ricy", "state": "0"}'::jsonb @? '$.city == "Ricy" && $.state == "0" ',     -- output: true
  '{"city": "Ricy", "state": "0"}'::jsonb @@ '$ ?(@.city == "Ricy" && @.state == "0")'; -- output: null

select
  '{"a":[1,2,3,4,5]}'::jsonb @? '$.a[*] ? (@ > 2)',   -- output: true
      '{"a":[1,2,3,4,5]}'::jsonb @@ '$.a[*] > 2',     -- output: true
  '{"a":[1,2,3,4,5]}'::jsonb @@ '$.a[*] ? (@ > 2)',   -- output: null 
      '{"a":[1,2,3,4,5]}'::jsonb @? '$.a[*] > 2';      -- output: true







'{"city": "Ricy", "state": "0"}'::jsonb @@ '$ ?(@.city == "Ricy" && @.state == "0")';
-- output: null expect output: true

'{"a":[1,2,3,4,5]}'::jsonb @@ '$.a[*] ? (@ > 2)',   -- output: null expect output true.

because i think array [a] do has number larger than 2 .  
can u help me ? Thank u .
```

Comment: Duplicate of [What's the difference between the PostgreSQL `@?` and `@@` JSONB Operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77046554/1048572)